# Mapbox GL 3D single building highlight selection

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

How can I highlight one single 3D building when hover over it? Something like the OSM buildings highlight feature. It seems the mapbox streets v7 building layer feature properties are so few, it only includes:

extrude
height
min_height
type
underground

There is no unique property to differentiate the building. Is there a way to include the address of the building or some unique ID?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. It depends on the data.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a unique per-building `id` in the Mapbox Streets v7 tileset. You may need to build your own tileset to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you! For building my own tileset, Is there an existing github project for me to start from (such as the one that build the Mapbox Streets v7), rather than from OSM directly?