# Mapbox GL JS Buildings Selection

Tags: javascript, 3d, mapbox

what I want to do is highlight some specific 3D buildings. I understand that there is not a unique ID that I can filter. In this post they suggest creating your own tileset ([Mapbox GL 3D single building highlight selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298274/mapbox-gl-3d-single-building-highlight-selection)). How would I go about creating a tileset that is a selection of the 3D model used in Mapbox? In other words, I would like to create a tileset of only 5 of these buildings and then add them as an overlay of the existing 3D buildings and color them differently. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a geoJSON of the buildings I wanted to highlight and added them as a layer. I used this example to get the coordinates and heights of the buildings (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/). I wish there was an easier (less time consuming) way of doing this.