# Mapbox for colour coding specific buildings

Tags: javascript, html, api, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to use Mapbox to color code specific buildings, with this website being the best example I can find (https://www.york.ac.uk/map/). In the same way, I want to pick specific buildings and have them separated by a color grading and title, however, I can't even seem to work out where to start with this in Mapbox Studio. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapbox GL 3D single building highlight selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298274/mapbox-gl-3d-single-building-highlight-selection)

Comment: You can't do that with the Mapbox buildings layer.